# Html - how to make the browsing button open in a desired path

Tags: php, html

I have this html code(+some backdoor php codes) to delete images from my website, but the problem is that I need that browsing dialoge to be opened in a specific path and be stuck on that path, I like I don't want the user to be able to navigate through the folders as he likes, is that possible to be done in any ways?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select a project : </td>
        <td><input type='file' name='userFile'><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="upload_btn" value="delete"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't … and it shows the user's local file system rather then the servers anyway.

Write some server side code to generate a list of files that could be deleted and generate an HTML document listing them instead.

Comment: I see.
I haven't uploaded the website yet, so it didn't make any trouble for me so far.